# jQuery/JS Not Registering Radio Button Values Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

---

I am working on a basic timed trivia game for my current school program, utilizing JavaScript and jQuery. As a simple overview, this trivia game employs 'radio buttons' to record user responses. Each button has a value of "1" ( for correct answer) or "0" (for wrong answer). However, no matter what I've tried or looked up, **I have been unable to resolve my current problem**: *jQuery/JavaScript will either say all answers inputted are either all "correct" OR "wrong"*.

As you will see in my code, this problem is specific to my `function responseCheck()` and `$("#submitButton").on("click", function()` functions.

In my `function responseCheck()` function, my logic is that by using this `$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function()` function, jQuery will go through all my the radio buttons that are checked; and then execute the following if/else statements:

- `if (parseInt($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()) === 1)` : using this I am saying  if the value of the button is equal to 1 (integer), then increment the `correctCount` variable.
- `else` : using this I am saying if the value isn't equal to 1 (integer), then increment the `wrongCount` variable.

Obviously, there is some tangent i'm not connecting to my issue. I appreciate all help received. Thank you in advance.

**PS**

- Ignore the commented out sections in my JS file, as they are bits of old/failed code
- The top two variables in my JS file were my attempts to use arrays to catalog right/wrong answers but that didn't work for me. Feel free to ignore these as well.
- I supplied my html file just for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //set up variables for game

    //var responsesArray = [];

    var correctAnswer = [1];

    var wrongAnswer = [0];

    //var buttonChecked = parseInt($("input[class='questions']:checked").val());

    var timer = 46;

    var timerInterval;

    var correctCount = 0;

    var wrongCount = 0;

    var noDoubleDip = false;

    //!! If extra time, add audio queues here!!

    // !!---------------


    //functions

    function timerCountDown() {

        timer--;

        if (timer > 0) {

            $("#timeLeft").text("Time Left: " + timer + " seconds");

            console.log(timer);

        }

        else {

            gameOver("fail");
        }

    }

    //function for when the game ends

    function gameOver(status) {

        clearInterval(timerInterval);

        if(status == 'success') {

            alert('You Did It');
        }

        else {

            alert('Time Ran Out');
        }

        console.log("times up!")


        $(".playScreen").hide();

        $(".bannerScreen").hide();

        $(".startScreen").hide();

        $(".endScreen").show();

        console.log("game's over!");

    }

    //function for going through responses; issue: COUNTS ALL FOR ONE <--- UNRESOLVED

    function responseCheck() {

        // responsesArray.push(buttonChecked);

      $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
        //debugger;
            if (parseInt($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()) === 1) {
                console.log("correct");
                correctCount++;
                $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);
            }

            else {
                console.log("incorrect");
                wrongCount++;
                $("#wrongCountDiv").text("wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
            }

        });

        // BELOW DID WORK BUT RAN THROUGH EACH question AT THE SAME TIME

        // // question 1

        // if (parseInt($("input[name='question1']:checked").val()) === 1) {

        //     console.log("correct");
        //     correctCount++;
        //     $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);

        // }
        // else {

        //     console.log("incorrect");
        //     wrongCount++;
        //     $("#wrongCountDiv").text("Wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);

        // }

    }

    //start game click event

    $("#startButton").on("click", function() {

        event.preventDefault();

        $(".playScreen").show();

        $(".bannerScreen").show();

        $(".startScreen").hide();

        $(".endScreen").hide();

        timerInterval = setInterval(timerCountDown, 1000);

    });

    //on click attempt to record user presses in quiz

  //  $("#submitButton").on("click", function() {


        // if (noDoubleDip) {
        //
        //     // event.preventDefault();
        //     //
        //     // attempt to prevent additional clicks from counting towards appropiate category -- UNRESOLVED <--
        //
        //     // above code actually stopped another button from being pressed
        //
        //     correctCount = "";
        //
        //     wrongCount = "";
        //
        // }
        //
        // noDoubleDip = true;
    // });

    //if the submit button is pressed before the time runs out

    $("#submitButton").on("click", function() {

        event.preventDefault();

        responseCheck();

        console.log("Finished before timer ran out");

        gameOver("success");

    });

    // $("input").on("click", function() {
    //
    //   if (correctAnswer[0]) {
    //
    //     console.log("Correct Input Received");
    //
    //   }
    //
    //   else {
    //
    //     console.log("Incorrect Input Received");
    //   }
    //
    // });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title> Poke-Trivia </title>

    <!--Meta-Viewport tag-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!--jQuery Link-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--javascript link-->
    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>

    <!--CSS link-->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Google Fonts link-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oregano|Sedgwick+Ave" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <h1> Pokemon Trivia </h1>

    <form>

        <!--START SCREEN BEGINS-->
        <div class="startScreen">

            <h2> Press the Pokeball to start! </h2>

            <button id="startButton"></button>

        </div>
        <!--END OF START SCREEN-->


        <h2 class="bannerScreen"> Answer 'em All </h2>

        <h2 class="bannerScreen" id="timeLeft"> Time Left: 45 seconds </h3>


        <!--START OF QUESTIONS-->

        <div class="playScreen">

            <p> Question 1: What is HM04 in GEN 1 (Red/Blue/Yellow)? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question1" value="0" id="1A">
                    <label for="1A"> Cut </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question1" value="0" id="1B">
                    <label for="1B"> Surf </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question1" value="1" id="1C">
                    <label for="1C"> Strength </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question1" value="0" id="1D">
                    <label for="1D"> Rock Smash </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 2: Who is the Gym Leader of Fuschia City in GEN 2/4 (Silver/Gold/Diamond/Pearl/Platinum)?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question2" value="0" id="2A">
                    <label for="2A"> Chuck </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question2" value="0" id="2B">
                    <label for="2B"> Koga </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question2" value="0" id="2C">
                    <label for="2C"> Whitney </label>

                    <input type="radio"  class="questions" name="question2" value="1" id="2D">
                    <label for="2D"> Janine </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 3: Which Water-type Pokemon was a "Starter" for GEN 2/4 (Silver/Gold/Diamond/Pearl/Platinum)?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question3" value="1" id="3A">
                    <label for="3A"> Totodile </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question3" value="0" id="3B">
                    <label for="3B"> Oshawott </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question3" value="0" id="3C">
                    <label for="3C"> Piplup </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question3" value="0" id="3D">
                    <label for="3D"> Mudkip </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 4: How many Legendary Pokemon were introduced in GEN 3 (Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald)?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question4" value="0" id="4A">
                    <label for="4A"> 3 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question4" value="1" id="4B">
                    <label for="4B"> 8 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question4" value="0" id="4C">
                    <label for="4C"> 6 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question4" value="0" id="4D">
                    <label for="4D"> 2 </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 5: In what region did GEN 6 (X/Y) take place?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question5" value="0" id="5A">
                    <label for="5A"> Johto </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question5" value="0" id="5B">
                    <label for="5B"> Unova </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question5" value="1" id="5C">
                    <label for="5C"> Kalos </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question5" value="0" id="5D">
                    <label for="5D"> Sinnoh </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 6: In GEN 7 (Sun/Moon), what "notable" exclusion was present in the game, when compared to its predecessors?</p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question6" value="1" id="6A">
                    <label for="6A"> Bicycles </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question6" value="0" id="6B">
                    <label for="6B"> Rare Candies </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question6" value="0" id="6C">
                    <label for="6C"> Pokemon Daycare </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question6" value="0" id="6D">
                    <label for="6D"> A Rival </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 7: In which year did the first ever Pokemon movie, featuring Mewtwo and Mew, release? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question7" value="0" id="7A">
                    <label for="7A"> 1998 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question7" value="1" id="7B">
                    <label for="7B"> 1999 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question7" value="0" id="7C">
                    <label for="7C"> 2000 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question7" value="0" id="7D">
                    <label for="7D"> 2001 </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 8: TRUE OR FALSE: Mark Hamill, of Star Wars fame, provided the voice of Entei in Pokemon 3: The Movie? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question8" value="0" id="8A">
                    <label for="8A"> True </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question8" value="1" id="8B">
                    <label for="8B"> False </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 9: Is it possible to teach "Fly" to Scyther (Bug, Flying type)? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question9" value="0" id="9A">
                    <label for="9A"> Yes, he does have wings after all. </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question9" value="1" id="9B">
                    <label for="9B"> No, Game Freak hates him. </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <p> Question 10: How many current, potential evolutions are there for Evee? </p>
            <hr>

                <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question10" value="0" id="10A">
                    <label for="10A"> 5 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question10" value="0" id="10B">
                    <label for="10B"> 6 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question10" value="0" id="10C">
                    <label for="10C"> 7 </label>

                    <input type="radio" class="questions" name="question10" value="1" id="10D">
                    <label for="10D"> 8 </label>
                </div>
            <br>

            <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit Answers</button>
        </div>

        <!-- End of Questions -->

        <!-- Start of End Screen -->

        <div class="endScreen">

            <h2> Here are your results </h2>
            <hr id="endScreenHr">

            <h2 id="correctCountDiv"> Correct Answers: 0</h2>
            <h2 id="wrongCountDiv"> Wrong Answers: 0</h2>

        </div>

        <!-- End of End Screen -->

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `.each()` is already providing you with each element per iteration as the keyword `$(this)`, by you using `$(parseInt($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()) === 1)` you are grabbing every element that is a radio button and checked, so `.val()` is giving you the value of the first element in the collection on each iteration, change your function to the following:

```
 $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {

            //if (parseInt($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()) === 1) { //NO
            if (parseInt($(this).val()) === 1) { //Check the .val() of the current radio button
                console.log("correct");
                correctCount++;
                $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);
            }

            else {
                console.log("incorrect");
                wrongCount++;
                $("#wrongCountDiv").text("wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
            }

        });
```

Comment: You are a wizard. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Redfearn-Justin No problem. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes. Shoot I spent a couple hours the other day wondering why a call to an API I am developing in .Net Core wasn't working, here it was because I forgot a word in my URL when making a test call. LOL. Anyway, it happens, if you are happy with my answer, please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your responseCheck():

```
  $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(i, e) {
    //debugger;
        if (parseInt($(e).val()) === 1) {
            console.log("correct");
            correctCount++;
            $("#correctCountDiv").text("Correct Answers: " + correctCount);
        }

        else {
            console.log("incorrect");
            wrongCount++;
            $("#wrongCountDiv").text("wrong Answers: " + wrongCount);
        }

    });
```